# Create plot only in some time frames

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have the following code to create a plot in pinescript.

`plot(line_to_plot, 'line_to_plot', color=color.lime, style=plot.style_circles, join = true)`

I only want to plot this in the 10mins timeframe. This plot is not to appear in other timeframes. The problem I face is that `plot()` cannot be used in conditional if statements in pinescript.

I am using pinescript v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a boolean and then set the boolean to true if the time frame is the 10m

```
bool = false
if timeframe.period == '10'
    bool := true

plot(bool ? line_to_plot : na,  'line_to_plot', color=color.lime, style=plot.style_circles, join = true)
```